# Como faço adicionar 3 imagens lado a lado e legenda em cima e embaixo em css

Tags: html, css

[image: Modelo que quero]

```
.produto{
    display: table;
    text-align: center;
    border-top: none;
    padding-top: 0;
    float: inline-start;
}

.prod1{
    display: table-caption;
    color: rgb(46, 146, 228);
    float: left;
    caption-side: top;
    padding: 5px;
    border: thin solid;
    margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
}

.prod2{
    display: table-caption;
    color: rgb(46, 146, 228);
    clear: center;
    caption-side: top;
    padding: 5px;
    border: thin solid;
    margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
}

.prod3{
    display: table-caption;
    color: rgb(46, 146, 228);
    float: right;
    caption-side: top;
    padding: 5px;
    border: thin solid;
    margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
    width: 100%;
}

<div class="produto">
    <span class="prod1">PRODUTO 1
        <img src="imgs/produto-1.jpg" alt="" title="PRODUTO 1">
    </span>
    <span class="prod2">PRODUTO 2
        <img src="imgs/produto-2.jpg" alt="" title="PRODUTO 2">
    </span>
    <span class="prod3">PRODUTO 3
        <img src="imgs/produto-3.jpg" alt="" title="PRODUTO 3">
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Não faz o menor sentido utilizar classes diferentes em cada div filha da div `.produto`. Até porque do jeito que está fazendo, todas as 3 classes que você criou possuem as mesmas propriedades com valores iguais. As classes não devem ser usadas dessa forma. Elas servem geralmente pra identificar grupos de elementos que possuem as mesmas propriedades. Então basta usar apenas uma classe para as 3 divs.

Você pode usar flexbox para fazer isso de uma forma bem mais simples e ainda mantendo a responsividade (evite usar `float` nesses casos). É preciso também definir uma dimensão para as imagens. Eu fiz assim:

```
.prod img{
   max-width: 100%;
}
```

Veja que as imagens terão no máximo 100% da largura da div `.prod`. Só é preciso ter atenção na propriedade `max-width` que deverá ter um valor máximo até a largura original da imagem, senão ela poderá "estourar" caso a largura da div seja maior. Por exemplo, se as imagens possuírem uma largura máxima de 300 pixels, você deve incluir a propriedade `max-width: 300px;`. Isso vai depender muito do seu layout.

Para adicionar texto acima e abaixo da imagem, você pode usar `<h3>` no texto de cima (já vem em negrito) ou outro `<h*>` (vai de `h1` a `h6`. Quanto menor o número, maior o texto) e `<p>` no texto de baixo.

**Veja:**

```css
.produto{
    display: flex;
    border-top: none;
    padding-top: 0;
}

.prod{
   flex: 1; /*distribui as 3 divs dentro do conteiner com larguras iguais*/
   margin: 5px; /*coloca uma margem entre elas*/
   text-align: center;
}

.prod img{
   max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="produto">
    <span class="prod">
         <h3>PRODUTO 1</h3>
        <img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" alt="" title="PRODUTO 1">
        <p>
            texto abaixo
        </p>
    </span>
    <span class="prod">
         <h3>PRODUTO 2</h3>
        <img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" alt="" title="PRODUTO 2">
        <p>
            texto abaixo
        </p>
    </span>
    <span class="prod">
         <h3>PRODUTO 3</h3>
        <img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" alt="" title="PRODUTO 3">
        <p>
            texto abaixo
        </p>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado cara, era exatamente isso que queria, muito obrigado mesmo! Estou aprendendo agora então vai desculpando a 'burrice'.

Comment: Legal cara! Então pode marcar a resposta.

Answer (score 1):

```
        h1{color: red; text-align: center;}
        #produtos {
            width: 800px;
            height: 350px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        .produto1, .produto2, .produto3 {
            width: 200px;
            height: 300px;
            background: ;
            float: left;
            padding: 0 20px 10px 0;
            margin-left: 20px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .preco { color: #A4A4A4; }
        span { color: #0080FF; }
        p { color:  #0080FF; text-transform: uppercase;}



<body>
    <h1>Produtos </h1>
    <hr>
    <hr>
    <div id="produtos">
        <div class="produto1">
            <p> Produto 1 </p>
            <img src="1.jpg" alt="">
            <p class="preco">Por Apenas <br><span> R$ 00,00</span></p>
        </div>
        <div class="produto2">
            <p> Produto 2 </p>
            <img src="1.jpg" alt="">
            <p class="preco">Por Apenas <br><span> R$ 00,00</span></p>
        </div>
        <div class="produto3">
            <p> Produto 3 </p>
            <img src="1.jpg" alt="">
            <p class="preco">Por Apenas <br><span> R$ 00,00</span></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <hr>
    <hr>
</body>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]